# column is ambiguous error

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Please help to solve the problem with the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT email_id as name, competition_id, end_date FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners, competition WHERE". DB_PREFIX . " competition.competition_id = ". DB_PREFIX ."competition_winners.competition_id";
```

I am getting the following error:
Notice: Error: Column 'competition_id' in field list is ambiguous
Error No: 1052
I am using opencart. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please google you error. It's easy

Comment: It's easy to minuse the question, I tried to google it and still didn't find any solutions to the problem

Comment: what did you google? tell us what all things you tried?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/2788326/mysql-user-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous-problem

Comment: that's the correct answer. didn't
 you read that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT email_id as name, c.competition_id, end_date FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners cw, competition  c WHERE cw.competition_id = c.competition_id";
```

The reason for error is that both table has 'competition_id'  field. So you need to specify the category_id field's table name.

Answer (score 0):

More tables has same column name competition_id.

try to prefix them in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT email_id as name, c.competition_id as competition_id, end_date FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners cw, competition c WHERE". DB_PREFIX . " competition.competition_id = ". DB_PREFIX ."competition_winners.competition_id";
```

Comment: Here I am getting an unknown column error on this too.

Comment: Please share output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE competition`

Answer (score 0):

Since your column `competition_id` is in more than one table you need to prepend with table `alias` to avoid the error

```
SELECT competition_winners.email_id as name, competition.competition_id, competition.end_date 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners as competition_winners, 
     ". DB_PREFIX . "competition as competition 
WHERE competition.competition_id = competition_winners.competition_id";
```

Comment: I am getting an unknown column error

Comment: What the error states? Please past the entire error

Comment: Notice: Error: Unknown column 'competition.competition_id' in 'where clause'
Error No: 1054
SELECT email_id as name, c.competition_id as competition_id, end_date FROM competition_winners cw, competition c WHERE competition.competition_id = competition_winners.competition_id ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,20 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sport\system\database\mysql.php on line 49

Comment: This is not my query, did you try mine?

Comment: Here what it is returning:

Comment: Notice: Error: Unknown column 'competition_winner.email_id' in 'field list'
Error No: 1054
SELECT competition_winner.email_id as name, competition.competition_id, competition.end_date FROM competition_winners as competition_winners, competition as competition WHERE competition.competition_id = competition_winners.competition_id ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,20 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sport\system\database\mysql.php on line 49

Comment: My bad, error should be fixed now, please try my updated query in answer